# How to roll multiple rows into one summary row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema and data:

```
create table chips (
  ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
  );

create table test_records (
  chip_id INTEGER,
  some_val VARCHAR (255),
  record INTEGER
  );

insert into chips values 
(1,'chip_1'),
(2,'chip_2');
insert into test_records values
(1,'thumbnail',53),
(1,'first_failure',42),
(1,'another_metric',33),
(2,'thumbnail',54)
```

Then I try and run the following sql:

```
select * 
FROM 
chips 
INNER JOIN test_records ON test_records.chip_id = chips.id
WHERE 
chips.id = 1
```

This works. I have a fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qMmJ6UxMfx8Fd87wgAsaBs/0

But what I want to do is something like

```
select
chip.id
test_record.thumbnail
test_record.first_failure
FROM 
test_records
INNER JOIN chips ON chips.id = test_record.chips
WHERE 
chips.id = 1
```

and have a single row that looks like

```
(chip_id:1, thumbnail:53,first_failure:42)
```

This doesn't work of course because thumbnail and first_failure are not columns. 
I basically want it to, where chip_id is 1 with those joins, look for the values in some_val where the value is thumbnail or first failure and attribute the record as that in the result.

I know this is kind of open ended. I don't even know where to start. Is this something where I need a pivot table? I don't know much about those but that it creates a temporary table during the query. Or do I need a subquery? Where I select (query for thumbnail record) AS thumbnail, (query for first_failure AS first failure). OR is it much easier and Im overcomplicating things..

Also any title improvements would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation:

```
select
    c.id,
    max(case when r.some_val  = 'thumbnail' then r.record end) thumbnail,
    max(case when r.some_val  = 'first_failure' then r.record end) first_failure
from 
    chips c
    inner join test_records r on c.id = r.chip_id
group by c.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qMmJ6UxMfx8Fd87wgAsaBs/2)**:

```
| id  | thumbnail | first_failure |
| --- | --------- | ------------- |
| 1   | 53        | 42            |
| 2   | 54        |               |
```

To filter on a given chip id, you can just add a `where` clause (it goes before the `group by` clause).

Answer (score 0):

The following comes close.  It returns:

```
id    value
1     (thumbnail:53, first_failure:42, another_metric:33)
```

The query is:

```
select c.id, '(' || string_agg(some_val || ':' || record, ', ') || ')' as value
FROM chips c INNER JOIN
     test_records tr
     ON tr.chip_id = c.id
WHERE c.id = 1
GROUP BY c.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f3ea1ea945a2e77990d6a500d3d0eb5) is a db<>fiddle.

It is easy to put `chip_id` into the string.  I'm just not sure if that is what you really want -- why would you leave out one measurement but include the id?

And, it occurs to me that you might really want JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use json to represent that result row. You can construct it using the [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), specifically the [aggregate function `json_object_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT chip_id, json_object_agg(some_val, record)
FROM test_records
GROUP BY chip_id
```

```
1   { "thumbnail" : 53, "first_failure" : 42, "another_metric" : 33 }
2   { "thumbnail" : 54 }
```

Now to get the chip id, or even better its name, in that object I can think of two approaches. The first one would use `jsonb_set` to create a new key in the aggregated object:

```
select jsonb_set(jsonb_object_agg(some_val, record), '{chip_name}'::text[], to_jsonb(name))
FROM chips 
INNER JOIN test_records ON test_records.chip_id = chips.id
GROUP BY id
```

The second would be to select the aggregate from a union:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)
FROM (TABLE test_records
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 'chip_id', id
  FROM chips) as kv(id, key, value)
GROUP BY id
```

([online demo of all queries](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b325eee51ee6f0a583957c295d51d237))

Of course you can also use a `WHERE` clause to filter for a single result instead of using the `GROUP BY id` demonstrated above. You might even be able to hardcode the value of the `chip_id` key:

```
SELECT json_object_agg(key, value)
FROM (SELECT some_val as key, record as value
  FROM test_records
  WHERE chip_id = 1
  UNION ALL
  VALUES ('chip_id', 1)
) kv
```

([online demo of all approaches](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6b4e606ce770a786acc13c1fcb559d17))